# Sorting on multiple columns w/ an output file per key

Tags: bash

I'm uncertain as to how I can use the until loop inside a while loop.

I have an input file of 500,000 lines that look like this:

```
   9       1       1  0.6132E+02
   9       2       1  0.6314E+02
  10       3       1  0.5874E+02
  10       4       1  0.5266E+02
  10       5       1  0.5571E+02
   1       6       1  0.5004E+02
   1       7       1  0.5450E+02
   2       8       1  0.5696E+02
  11       9       1  0.6369E+02
  .....
```

And what I'm hoping to achieve is to sort the numbers in the first column in numerical order such that I can pull all the similar lines (eg. lines that start with the same number) into new text files `"cluster${i}.txt"`. From there I want to sort the fourth column of (`"cluster${i}.txt"`) files in numerical order. After sorting I would like to write the first row of each sorted `"cluster${i}.txt"` file into a single output file. A sample output of `"cluster1.txt"` would like this:

```
 1       6       1  0.5004E+02
 1       7       1  0.5450E+02
 1      11       1  0.6777E+02 
 ....
```

as well as an output.txt file that would look like this:

```
 1       6       1  0.5004E+02
 2     487       1  0.3495E+02
 3      34       1  0.0344E+02
 ....
```

Here is what I've written:

```
#!/bin/bash

input='input.txt'
i=1

sort -nk 1 $input > 'temp.txt'

while read line; do
   awk -v var="$i" '$1 == var' temp.txt > "cluster${i}.txt"
     until [[$i -lt 20]]; do
     i=$((i+1))
   done
done

for f in *.txt; do
   sort -nk 4 > temp2.txt
   head -1 temp2.txt
   rm temp2.txt
done > output.txt
```

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: ...btw, this would be **much** better to do (faster, more efficient) with one big `awk` script, not a bunch of tiny little awk invocations inside a shell loop.

Comment: ...similarly, `> foo` is actually an expensive operation -- every time a line with that redirection is run, it opens `foo` for output before the command and closes it after. You're much better off from an efficiency perspective keeping the file open longer.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to have all these temporary files instead of just working with pipelines.

Comment: I would start with a `sort` command that sorts the input file by columns 1 and 4. Pipe that to an `awk` script that writes to the output fies.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your suggestions - making temp files seemed reasonable to me in terms of keeping everything straight, but I see how including pipes would be faster here.

Comment: @Barmar - that makes sense, I'll try that

Comment: BTW, arguably this was an XY question -- ("I'm asking about X, but what I really want to do is Y"); it's worth keeping questions focused on your goal, not the tool you're thinking might be most appropriate to the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only takes one line, if your `sort -n` knows how to handle exponential notation:

```
sort -nk 1,4 <in.txt | awk '{ of="cluster" $1 ".txt"; print $0 >>of }'
```

...or, to also write the first line for each index to `output.txt`:

```
sort -nk 1,4 <in.txt | awk '
  {
    if($1 != last) {
      print $0 >"output.txt"
      last=$1
    }
    of="cluster" $1 ".txt";
    print $0 >of
  }'
```

Consider using an `awk` implementation -- such as GNU awk -- which will cache file descriptors, rather than reopening each output file for every append; this will greatly improve performance.

---

By the way, let's look at what was wrong with the original script:

- It was slow. Really, *really* slow.

  Starting a new instance of `awk` 20 times for every line of input (because the whole point of `while read` is to iterate over individual lines, so putting an `awk` inside a `while read` is going to run `awk` *at least* once per line) is going to have a very appreciable impact on performance. Not that it was actually doing this, because...
- The `while read line` outer loop was reading from stdin, not `temp.txt` or `input.txt`.
  Thus, the script was hanging if stdin didn't have anything written on it, or wasn't executing the contents of the loop at all if stdin pointed to a source with no content like `/dev/null`.
- The inner loop wasn't actually processing the `line` read by the outer loop. `line` was being read, but all of `temp.txt` was being operated on.
- The `awk` wasn't actually inside the inner loop, but rather was inside the outer loop, just *before* the inner loop. Consequently, it wasn't being run 20 times with different values for `i`, but run only once per line read, with whichever value for `i` was left over from previously executed code.
- Whitespace is important to how commands are parsed. `[[foo]]` is wrong; it needs to be `[[ foo ]]`.

To "fix" the inner loop, to do what I imagine you meant to write, might look like this:

```
# this is slow and awful, but at least it'll work.
while IFS= read -r line; do
  i=0
  until [[ $i -ge 20 ]]; do
    awk -v var="$i" '$1 == var' <<<"$line" >>"cluster${i}.txt"
    i=$((i+1))
  done
done <temp.txt
```

...or, somewhat better (but still not as good as the solution suggested at the top):

```
# this is a somewhat less awful.
for (( i=0; i<=20; i++ )); do
  awk -v var="$i" '$1 == var' <temp.txt >"cluster${i}.txt"
  head -n 1 "cluster${i}.txt"
done >output.txt
```

Note how the redirection to `output.txt` is done *just once, for the whole loop* -- this means we're only opening the file once.

Comment: Glad to help. I've also amended with a breakdown of what the old script was doing wrong, which you might find helpful.